# selecting rows after the id given the order

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Given a table like the following:

```
id     quantity
1      5
2      3
3      7
4      2
5      8
```

Given a id and the order, I want to select all rows that would come after the given id if ordered in the given order. For example, if the id was 1 and the order was "quantity desc", I want to get

```
id    quantity
2     3
4     2
```

How can I do this with just sql. I can only think of a way combining php and sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery for this:

```
select t.*
from t
where quantity < (select t2.quantity from t t2 where t2.id = 1)
order by quantity desc;
```